# Authorization custom middleware not reached in .Net8 isolated worker Azure HttpTrigger function

Tags: azure-functions, authorization, middleware

I am trying to write middleware to
a) bypass AuthorizationLevel.Function when calling the API from a specific domain (of a Blazor Wasm application so that I dont expose a key in the client).
b) When not called from the application domain, check the api key and return unauthorised if the key is wrong or missing.

At any rate, the middleware is initialized but not accessed when a function is called (in Dev mode), i.e. the ctor is accessed on startup but Invoke() is never called.

Am I missing something? Can this work?

BTW, this idea comes from CoPilot so it may be bonkers. Is it?

My middleware (which still needs work) is:

```
public class CustomMiddleware : IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware
{
    public CustomMiddleware()
    {
            
    }
    public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        HttpRequestData req = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();
        var host = req.Headers.GetValues("Host").FirstOrDefault() ?? "";

        if (host == "your_specific_domain")
        {
            // Bypass the authorization for the specific domain
            await next(context);
        }
        else
        {
            // Apply the AuthorizationLevel.Function authorization
            string functionKey = req.Headers.GetValues("x-functions-key").FirstOrDefault() ?? "";
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(functionKey))
            {
                context.GetHttpResponseData().WriteString("Unauthorized");
                return;
            }

            await next(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And it is initialized in program.cs by:

```
services.AddSingleton<IFunctionsWorkerMiddleware, CustomMiddleware>();
```

In the trigger I test to see if the context was changed with:

```
if (executionContext.GetHttpResponseData() != null)
{
    return executionContext.GetHttpResponseData();
}
```

Comment: My middleware (which still needs work) is? How are you using this in Function.cs?